# asp.net mvc Problems with simple LINQ statement with a list within a list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have been putting together a dynamic menu in asp.net-core MVC 6 using [this Blog](http://techiejourney.com/asp-net-5-view-components-building-a-bootstrap-navigation-menu/).

I have a menuItem object that I wish to select a subset of objects based on two criteria. Here is the Menu Object:

```
 public class MenuItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool Divider { get; set; }
    public bool Header { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string MenuItemText { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Roles { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public MenuItem()
    {

    }

    public MenuItem(int id, bool divider, bool header, string action, string controller, string menuItemText, IList<string> roles,int parentid)
    {
        Id = id;
        Divider = divider;
        Header = header;
        ActionName = action;
        ControllerName = controller;
        MenuItemText = menuItemText;
        Roles = roles;
        ParentId = parentid;
    }
 }
```

A list of these items was populated using a line like:

```
MenuList.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem(100, false, false, "Index", "Scheduler", "Scheduling", new List<string>() { "Admin", "Technician" }, 0));
```

I can select those MenuItems based on ParentId using this line and it works:

```
_menuData.GetUnAuthorizedMenus().Result.MenuItems.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
```

and in particular:

```
MenuItems.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId).ToList();
```

How do I select those lines where ParentId == parentId and

Roles == "Admin".

In menuItem there is a list of roles this MenuItem belongs to and I want to select those items based on whether they have a specific role in that list.

How do you select only those menuItems with a specific role in the sublist as well as ParentId as above...

Comment: You can use a `.Contains()` clause - `.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId && s.Roles.Contains("Admin"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
MenuItems.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId && s.Roles.Contains("Admin")).ToList();
```

or maybe

```
MenuItems.Where(s => s.ParentId == parentId && s.Roles.Count() == 1 && s.Roles.Contains("Admin")).ToList();
```

If you want menu items with *only* the Admin role

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should return record where Id = parent id and sublist where role is admin.

```
menuItems.Where(x => x.Id == parentId).Where(z => z.Roles.Any(y => y == "Admin"));
```

And if you want to filter sublist also then use

```
menuItems.Where(x => x.Id == parentId).select(child => new MenuItems
{
//Populate parent properties
Roles = child.Roles.Where(x=>x=="Admin")
});
```